# Como usar loop for?

Tags: c#

Como usar *loop* for nisso? Já tentei de todo jeito sempre da erro.

Vou me expresar melhor !

o que eu nao estou conseguindo e que essa repetiçao de Metrotiles 1 2 3 4 5 seja apena um em loope for i , então seria apenas metrotile[i] . alguma coisa 
e nao teria  a necessidade fazer repetidamente

```
metroTile1.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile2.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile3.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile4.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile5.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile6.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile7.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile8.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile9.UseCustomBackColor = true;
metroTile10.UseCustomBackColor = true;
```

Já tentei desta maneira

```
MetroTile a = new MetroTile();
a[i].UseCustomBackColor = true;
```

Ja tentei desta Tambem

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    MetroTile a = new MetroTile();
    metroTile.UseCustomBackColor = true(a);
}
```

Comment: o que preciso nesse Metrotile eh adiconar o numero que naoestou conseguindo em loop Metrotile 1 Metrotile 2  da sempre erro

Comment: E o tipo `MetroTile` é iterável?

Comment: é da interface metro, entendi, mas da onde eles vêm ?

Comment: acontece a mesma coisa  o programas pede para criar um aclasse interna MetroTile

Comment: @CarlosCoelho MetroTile não seria uma classe?

Comment: tá difícil ajudar

Comment: Perguntada 21 minutos atrás já com -7 votos. Temos um recorde aqui!

Comment: Não vou votar negativo e estou tentando te ajudar. O que é `metroTile1`, `metroTile2`, `metroTile3`, etc? Onde e como você declara essas variáveis?

Comment: Ele quer utilizar um mesmo método para todos os objetos do tipo "MetroTitle". Sem precisar mexer em um por um, está bem claro.

Comment: @CarlosCoelho acredito que a resposta do Marcio Cristian irá te ajudar, verifique e marque como "aceita" caso resolva seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tá criando em tempo de execução, o código teria de ser assim:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   var metrotile = new MetroTile();
   metrotile.UseCustomBackColor = true;

   //aqui vc adicionaria em um Control ou em uma lista qualquer
   this.Controls.Add(metrotile);
}
```

Agora se você já criou pelo designer, você vai ter de pegar a lista dos Tiles de alguma forma, exemplo:

```
var listaTiles = this.Controls.OfType<MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTile>().Select(t => t);
```

Ai você percorreria a lista novamente depois

Comment: foi da sua maneira que foi criado pelo tempo de execuçao e agradeço a sua resposta